# Android: Same activity for different buttons, but different actions

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-button

I was wondering if there is any way to call the same activity for different buttons, but do different things for each one..
More specific.. I have one activity with about 10 buttons on it and if I do it traditionally, every time I press a button, I have to create an activity for each one and as a result, I will have more than 15 java files.. 
So, I was wondering if there is any way, all the buttons, show to the same activity (which is easy, I will "intent" to show the same activity), but on that activity, depending on the button I press, do different actions.. 
 
For example, all the buttons show on Buttons.java, but inside exist a TextView and every time show another text, depending on the buttons I press -> Text1 (for Button1), Text2 (for Button2), Text3 (for Button3)...
Do you have any ideas?? Thank you!!

Comment: Your main activity as you describe it has the button list. When a button is clicked, you get a new view (e.g. the one with the `Textview`), which needs to be a new `Activity` or same activity but different `Fragment`. To pass the different text in the case of a new activity, you should use`intent.putExtra()`. If you use `Fragment`, you should use `fragment.setArguments()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass some information to activity when you want to start it... for example:

```
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ExampleActivity.class);
                //There is no limit for number of Extras you want to pass to activity
                intent.putExtra("buttonNumber", 1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

ExampleActivity.java

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

int pressedButtonNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_poll);
    pressedButtonNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("buttonNumber");
    switch(pressedButtonNumber){
         case 1:
         //Do Something for clicking button 1 scenario
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example!!! The first part, it works great, every button send me to the same activity... Unfortunatelly the second part, I have two errors.. The first one is on "switch(buttonNumber)", where it says it cannpt resorlve symbole 'buttonNumber' and the other is on number 1 where it says "Constant expression required".. Do you have any ideas?? Thank you!!

Comment: I found it... You propably didn't saw it, it is not switch(buttonNumber) but switch(pressedButtonNumber).... when I correct this, everything solved!!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @nigi I didn't write these codes in IDE so i didn't notice that there is a problem... I will correct it... and Your welcome ;)